# R: Manual line break within strings for HTML table output

Tags: r

I am working on a replication of a table in R as an HTML output with `huxtable`, and came accross a basic question I can't answer:
Is there an easy way to add a line break in a string?

Example:

```
[1]  State with highest mortality rate compared to Population   Population   Deaths

[2]  Alabama                                                    16,000,000   15
[3]  Alaska                                                     3,000,000    7   
...
```

I would like to break lines manually, since it is a replication project.

Possible end-result:

```
[1]  State with highest
     mortality rate compared 
     to Population                   Population   Deaths

[2]  Alabama                         16,000,000   15
[3]  Alaska                          3,000,000    7
...
```

Let me know, if anyone found a good solution. Thank you in advance for helping and sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Add breaks in HTML with `<br>` and set `escape_contents` to `FALSE` for the relevant cells.

```
myhux[1, 1] <- "State with highest<br> mortality rate compared <br> to population"
escape_contents(myhux)[1, 1] <- FALSE
```